# Does your heart skip a beat when you sneeze?

Tags: biology, physiology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does your heart stop beating when you sneeze?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6151/does-your-heart-stop-beating-when-you-sneeze)

In [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/6153/651) to the question [Does your heart stop beating when you sneeze?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6151/does-your-heart-stop-beating-when-you-sneeze) it is stated that your heart can **skip a beat** when you sneeze?

Is that even possible?

Comment: It doesn't say does the heard really skips a beat, but talks about the *sensation* of that, with "skip a beat" in double-quotes. As I read the full text quote in the answer, the next beat is simply delayed due to internal pressure. It's not that there is one beat missing.

Comment: I see no significant difference between stopping for a short time and skipping a beat, closing as duplicate.